# iOS 11 Onboarding screen

Tags: ios

[image: Screenshot]

I want to make an onboarding screen similar to the new iOS 11 one. Is there a template I can use? The button style does not appear in the standard either.

[Onboarding](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/onboarding/)
[Onboarding - Archive](http://archive.is/2017.10.18-083202/https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/app-architecture/onboarding/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#walkthrough--intro--tutorial) should have a couple of options that would suite you.